# Delete when UserID = 1 and CourseID not in array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sql-delete, notin

This is the SQL code I am using:

For some reason it deletes all records for the UserID but does not take into account the NOT IN array.  I need it to delete only if the user ID = the current user AND the courseID of that user is not in the array..

```
mysql_query("DELETE FROM tblLinkUserCourse WHERE ((UserID=$CurrentUserID) AND (CourseID NOT IN ({$new_array})))");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Remove all unnecessary `()` from query.

2) Check `$new_array` contains all your course_id or not and constructed as string. If not constructed as string and comma separated use this code.

```
$new_array = implode(',', $new_array);
mysql_query("DELETE FROM tblLinkUserCourse WHERE UserID=$CurrentUserID AND CourseID NOT IN ({$new_array})");
```

Answer (score 0):

Is $new_array PHP array or string prepared for query?
If it is array you should use:

```
$new_array = implod(',', $new_array);
mysql_query("DELETE FROM tblLinkUserCourse WHERE ((UserID=$CurrentUserID) AND (CourseID NOT IN ({$new_array})))");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$new_array  = "'".implode("', ", $new_array)."'";
$sql        = "DELETE FROM tblLinkUserCourse WHERE ((UserID=$CurrentUserID) AND (CourseID NOT IN ({$new_array})))";
```